# Add delete action for a row in Flutter using DataTable2

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to figure out a way to add a delete button to this table to delete a row .
I want to add a button that will delete the selected row which contains 6 columns.

I'm using this package [Data_table_2](https://pub.dev/packages/data_table_2) .

And this my code :

```
   class DataTable2SimpleDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const DataTable2SimpleDemo();

  @override
  State<DataTable2SimpleDemo> createState() => _DataTable2SimpleDemoState();
}

class _DataTable2SimpleDemoState extends State<DataTable2SimpleDemo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Container(
          child: DataTable2(
              columnSpacing: 12,
              horizontalMargin: 12,
              minWidth: 600,
              columns: [
                DataColumn2(
                  label: Text('Column A'),
                  size: ColumnSize.L,
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('Column B'),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('Column C'),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('Column D'),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('Column NUMBERS'),
                  numeric: true,
                ),
              ],
              rows: List<DataRow>.generate(
                  100,
                  (index) => DataRow(cells: [
                        DataCell(Text('A' * (10 - index % 10))),
                        DataCell(Text('B' * (10 - (index + 5) % 10))),
                        DataCell(Text('C' * (15 - (index + 5) % 10))),
                        DataCell(Text('D' * (15 - (index + 10) % 10))),
                        DataCell(Text(((index + 0.1) * 25.4).toString()))
                      ]))),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use visibility widget.

[visibility widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html)